# Visual Studio Code - Node app with Chrome Debugger Conflict

Tags: node.js, angular, express, visual-studio-code

I currently have the following `launch.json` in my Visual Studio Code app.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [        
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\server\\server.js"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200/",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///*": "/*"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Chrome, with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            /*"diagnosticLogging": true,*/
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200/*",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///*": "/*"
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

I would like to know how to configure Visual Studio Code to launch both my Angular 4 app and Node Express backend under the same port so that I can debug both sides with a simple `f5`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me to get my React app and Express server up and running just by hitting one option. This is my setup:

My `launch.json` file which uses the `compounds` attribute. Using this attribute, I can now select `Server/Client` from the `Run` menu to launch both my client and server projects. You'll see in the `chrome` launch section, I call a `preLaunchTask` which you can see defined below. Also you'll see I am using nodemon as my executable below. You could remove this and `runtimeArgs` if you just want to use node as your executable.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [

    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch_Client_App",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000/",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/client/public/index.html",
      "preLaunchTask": "start_debugging"
    },
    {
      "name": "Launch_Server",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
      "trace": true,
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/path/to/start_up_file.js",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--watch",
        "server"
      ],
      "restart": true,
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
  ],

  "compounds": [
    {
        "name": "Server/Client",
        "configurations": ["Launch_Client_App", "Launch_Server"]
    }
  ]
}
```

`tasks.json` which defines my prelaunch task as shown above. You'll see here I call a bash script `debug.sh` which you can see below.

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [    
      {
        "label": "start_debugging",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "./debug.sh",
        "windows": {
            "command": ".\\debug.cmd"
        },
        "isBackground": true,
        "group": {
            "kind": "test",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "problemMatcher": {
            "owner": "custom",                      //This is not needed but, required by the problemMatcher Object
            "pattern": {
                "regexp": "^$"                      //This is not needed but, required by the problemMatcher Object
            },
            "background": {
                "activeOnStart": true,
                "beginsPattern": "Compiling...",    //Signals the begin of the Task
                "endsPattern": "Compiled .*"        //Signals that now the initialisation of the task is complete
            }
        },
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "always",
            "panel": "new"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

`debug.sh` is a Node script I call to start up my client side project. I have my `client` and `server` folders living together, next to each other in my directory, so I have to `cd` and then start my React app.

```
node start-client.js
```

and then `start-client.js` looks like:

```
const args = [ 'start' ];
const opts = { stdio: 'inherit', cwd: 'client', shell: true };
require('child_process').spawn('npm', args, opts);
```

And that's it! My client app runs in the vscode's `Debug Console` and the Node app runs in the `Terminal` inside vscode. This is important, because above in `launch.json` you'll see I define this for the Node app: `"console": "integratedTerminal"` which ensures the client and server output don't collide.

Answer (score 0):

In your node configuration, specify the `"cwd"` key:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\server\\server.js",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\server"
}
```